# I am using `max()` to get the highest value from n digits?

Tags: python

My teacher solved this question "Write a function which takes a n digits number as an input and return True if the biggest digit in this number is divisible by 3" like this:

```
def is_divisable(n):
    a = str(n)
    b = 0
    for i in a:
        if int(i)>b:
            b = int(i)

    if b % 3 == 0:
        return "True"
print is_divisable(67479)
```

I have thought of it in another way but my code is not working and
I am getting an error says:

> "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

```
def is_dvo(n):


    if max(n) % 3 == 0:
        return True

print is_dvo(67479)
```

Comment: start by `a = int(max(str(n)))`

Comment: max/min can be used on a list/string and in your example, you try to do that on a integer! That is reason for type error!

Comment: Also, you are not returning a value when the condition is not `True` (well, technically you are returning `None`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't quite say what your question is, but if you want another way to solve the problem,

```
def is_divisable(n):
    return int(max(str(n))) % 3 == 0
```

This code converts the number to its decimal string representation, finds the largest digit (as a character), changes that digit to an integer, checks if that is divisible by 3, then returns that answer.

If your question is why you are getting that error, your parameter `n` is an integer, and you try to apply the `max()` function to that integer. However, `max()` is supposed to be used on iterable objects such as strings, lists, tuples, generators, and so on. My code changes the integer to a string before using `max()` so it does not have that problem, and it iterates over the digits in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can condense the code to a single line:

```
def is_divisable(n):
  return max(map(int, str(n)))%3 == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
max(str(n), key=int) in {'3', '6', '9'}
```

Comment: You left out the possibility that the largest digit is zero, as in the number `0`.